# VBA Average Function Error - 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting an error 'Unable to get average property of Worksheetfunction class' when attempting to calculate the average of 2 ranges.

My table can be found below.

When I calculate the average of the % column, I have no problems.  It provides me with the correct output, however, I have problems when I try and calculate the average for the $ column.

```
Col |   %    | $ 
1   | 2.33%  | $2.33
2   | 3.64%  | $3.64 
3   | 10.83% | $10.83
4   | 6.07%  | $6.07
5   |   -    | - 
6   | 12.99% | $12.99
7   | 18.99% | $18.99


  Dim myRange As Range
  Dim myAverage As Variant

 'The user selects the range
 Set myRange = Application.InputBox( _
 prompt:="Please select the range", Title:="My Range", Type:=8)

 'This splits the range into two areas because the user typically does not select the row with the "-" in it.  
 'myRange would typically look something like (B1:B4,B6:B7) OR (C1:C4,C6:C7)
 Area1 = myRange.Areas(1)
 Area2 = myRange.Areas(2)

 myAverage = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Area1, Area2)
```

The error I receive is 'Unable to get average property of Worksheetfunction class' and it happens with the myAverage calculation.

Any ideas as to why it calculates the % column without problem, but doesn't calculate the $ column?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the types of `Area1, Area2`? I don't see them declared anywhere.

Comment: @John Coleman they are ranges

Comment: If the data is string/text in the $ column, the Average function will return an DIV/0 error.

Comment: If they are Range variables then `Area1 = myRange.Areas(1)` is an error (no `Set`). If they are variants, then that line assigns the *values* of the range to the variables.

Comment: They *aren't* ranges :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare as the proper type (Range object):

```
Dim Area1 As Range
Dim Area2 As Range
```

Use the `Set` keyword to assign to Object variables.

```
Set Area1 = myRange.Areas(1)
Set Area2 = myRange.Areas(2)
```

Then, you should be able to use the `Application.Average` or `Application.WorksheetFunction.Average` to get the mean.

```
myAverage Application.Average(Area1, Area2)
```

Otherwise, you're passing a variant array to the function, which is not supported, hence it raises the error. The `Average` function requires either a contiguous range of multiple cells, or itemized list of *individual cells* or values. You can't pass it multiple ranges of multiple cells each.

Or, omit the `Area1/Area2` steps entirely and do simply:

```
myAverage = Application.Average(myRange.Areas(1), myRange.Areas(2))
```

Comment: can you clarify?  What do you mean markup text?  When I check the format of each cell in the $ column, it shows that it is "Currency".

Comment: @user2828701 in your original example, you were showing `<br>` tags in the cell data. If that's not the case (per your edit) then my answer may not be applicable anymore.

Comment: yea, those breaks aren't actually there.  Just needed to shift the data to another line

Comment: see revision @user2828701